# ADC differential input question

Tags: adc, differential

[image]
For example I have a 10 bits ADC，which has a reference voltage of 2.5V.
In single-ended mode,the input range 0-2.5V according with conversion result 0-2*e10.
And what about the differential mode？
I have two question,in differential mode,is the votage range -2.5V-2.5V?
and -2.5V-2.5V according with conversion result 0-2*e10?
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Which ADC are you referring to?

Comment: Not to specific ADC,I am just confused with the mixed relation from single-ended input and differential input to unipolar and bipolar mode. And @MarkU had give a detailed answer.Also thank for your kind  anwser

Answer (score 2):

ADC 10-bit resolution means there are pow(2,10)=1024 possible output codes.

If the **transfer function** is **unipolar** with voltage range 0 to 2.5V, then ideally each code is (2.5V)/1024=0.0024414V and the maximum full-scale voltage is (2.5V)*(1023/1024)=2.49756V. Real measurement will have some **offset error** and some **gain error** specified in the ADC datasheet Electrical Characteristics table.

If the **transfer function** is **bipolar** with **2's complement codes**, with voltage range -2.5 to 2.5V (a **span** or **dynamic range** of 5.0V), then ideally each code is (5.0V)/1024=0.004883V and the maximum full-scale voltage is (5.0V)*(511/1024)=2.495117V. Real measurement will have some **offset error** and some **gain error** specified in the ADC datasheet Electrical Characteristics table. Note that in 2's complement, the 1024 possible output codes have the range -512 to +511.

If the input is **single-ended** that means that the input voltage is sampled with respect to analog ground (which must be close to digital ground). Usually single-ended input is used with unipolar transfer function, because the smaller LSB voltage gives more detail.

If the input is **differential** that means that the input voltage is sampled as the algebraic difference between two analog input pins, such as AINP and AINN. The signal would be (AINP)-(AINN). Both input pins must also be within a specified **common-mode** input range, such as between AVDD and AGND. If AINP is 1.5V and AINN is 2.1V, then the signal would be -0.6V, even though both AINP>0 and AINN>0. Usually differential input is used with a bipolar transfer function, so that both positive and negative signals can be encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed anwser,now i realize that single-ended usually together with unipolar mode and differential input usually together with bipolar.Really a big help from you.